# Memory size of a hash or other object?

Tags: ruby

What's the best way to get the size of a given hash (or any object really) in bytes in Ruby 1.9.3?

The solution to "[Find number of bytes a particular Hash is using in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687073/find-number-of-bytes-a-particular-hash-is-using-in-ruby)" does not appear to be valid in 1.9.3, because `memsize_of` isn't in the documentation for [ObjectSpace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html).

Comment: Do you want to know the size of it recursively, or just the Hash itself?  I mean, if you already have objects stored in other variables, but also in the Hash, do you want to consider them as contributing to the Hash size? (Having one object in more than one place doesn't use twice the memory). /Just thinking about how to do this in the underlying C API.

Comment: Good question. I'm just interested in the hash itself, and the string values contained therein.

Comment: Question seems similar to this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973094/how-to-measure-the-size-of-a-ruby-object

Comment: You are not supposed to offer monetary compensation for answers on Stack Overflow. There is a whole system of incentives in place and money is not a part of it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[`ObjectSpace.memsize_of`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-memsize_of) [does work](http://ideone.com/DhEMnt) in 1.9.3, documented or not:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION #=>1.9.3

require 'objspace'

p ObjectSpace.memsize_of("a"*23)    #=> 23 
p ObjectSpace.memsize_of("a"*24)    #=> 24 
p ObjectSpace.memsize_of("a".*1000) #=> 1000
h = {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
p ObjectSpace.memsize_of(h)         #=> 116
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for 2.1.4 it does't. `ObjectSpace.memsize_of("a"*23)` returns `0`

Comment: This is because now it represent the memory outside of the ruby heap

Comment: What exactly does this method return, the size in bytes of the object in memory?

Comment: Even the doc page for `ObjectSpace#memsize_of` doesn't list what the units are. Incredibly annoying to have to hunt for something basic.

Comment: @JaredMenard, I believe they are bits

Comment: **ObjectSpace.memsize_of returns bytes**. I've compared results with `NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::MemorySampler.new.sampler.get_sample` which gives its result in MB ([proof](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/2bc79e102185861ff078fd15ccbf31a32f088b8a/lib/new_relic/agent/samplers/memory_sampler.rb#L111)) and obtained that the ratio between both is `1024*1024`. Hence it's bytes.

Comment: In ruby 2.6.4 `ObjectSpace.memsize_of("a"*23)` returns 40. Not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using on an ActiveRecord object, convert it to json first. E.g.: `ObjectSpace.memsize_of(User.all.to_json)`

Answer (score 11):

I once had the same problem. You have to be aware, that the real size is almost impossible to determine, since it depends on which VM you are using, which version of the VM and so on. Also, if you are referencing a string, that is also referenced somewhere else, then unsetting your hash doesn't mean that the specific contained string will also be unset, since it is already referenced somewhere else.

I once wrote an analyzer to count the estimated size of objects, by going through all contained objects in the given object. Get inspired to write your own:

https://github.com/kaspernj/knjrbfw/blob/master/lib/knj/memory_analyzer.rb#L334

Mine works like this:

```
require "rubygems"
require "knjrbfw"

analyzer = Knj::Memory_analyzer::Object_size_counter.new(my_hash_object)

puts "Size: #{analyzer.calculate_size}"
```

Comment: this code exist error! it should be like this: `analyzer = Knj::Memory_analyzer::Object_size_counter.new(my_hash_object)`

Answer (score -3):

An alternative way of having a **rough estimate** of the size of a hash is to convert it into a string and count the number of characters, each character will be a byte.

```
hash = {hello:  "world"}
=> {:hello=>"world"}
hash.to_s
=> "{:hello=>\"world\"}"
hash.to_s.size
=> 17
```

Then you can use a [characters to bytes/megabytes calculator](http://extraconversion.com/data-storage/characters/characters-to-megabytes.html)

Comment: This post is misleading, the above mentioned hash takes 232 bytes instead of 17: `require('objspace');ObjectSpace.memsize_of({hello:  "world"}) => 232`

Comment: For more complicated nested hashes makes sense to convert to string `to_s` to calculate the size, if you try `ObjectSpace.memsize_of(deep_hash)` you won't get a wrong size.

Comment: @David why is the difference so large. I would have though `.to_s.size` would give a good estimate.